# Why do mp4 files play so slow when using Red5 with rtmp and jwplayer?

Tags: jwplayer, rtmp, red5

I have a Red5 server running and I am trying to stream a .mp4 file using rtmp.

I have my video files located at **red5/webapps/vod/streams**.

My client code is shown below. If I try streaming a .flv file everything seems to work fine but when I try streaming a .m4p file it has a hard time starting and plays extremely slow without any sound.

**What can I do to get the .mp4 file streaming correctly?**

My jwplayer:

```
<html>
  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/i6WMuWEv.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="container">&nbsp;</div>
    <script>
    var playerInstance = jwplayer("container");
    playerInstance.setup({
        file: "rtmp://localhost:1935/vod/testVid.mp4", <!-- testVid.flv, -->
        primary: "flash",
        width:640,
        height:360
    });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Speed when starting using mp4 may require that you realign your media for streaming. This means that you use a utility to place the moov atom from the end of the file after the mdat atom to the beginning. Its most probably not red5 itself.

Comment: @PaulGregoire Thanks for the response, I will look more into what you said and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: @PaulGregoire After doing some more research it looks like the video files I am using might actually be .mov files that had their extensions switched to .mp4.  I think this might be the case because I tried to use AtomaticParsley to look at the file atoms and go the following errror: "AtomicParsley error: Quicktime movie files are not supported." I tried using an online file converter to convert the thought to be .mp4 file to an actual .mp4 and was able to get the new converted file to both stream with my test jwplayer and to work with the AtomaticParsley command.